# Convert Ember function to use ES2017 async/await

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ecmascript-2017

I'd like to convert this Ember route action to use ES2017 async / await. Can someone please explain what this would look like?

Per spec, I already added: babel: `{ includePolyfill: true }` to my ember-cli-build.js file:

```
save() {
      let tenant = this.modelFor(this.routeName).tenant;
      let app = this.modelFor(this.routeName).app;

      return tenant.save().then(()=> {
        return tenant.get('app').save({ adapterOptions: { tenantId: tenant.id }}).then(() => {
          this.transitionTo('tenants.tenant.info', tenant.id);
        }).catch((error) => {
          tenant.get('app').rollback();
          throw error;
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        tenant.rollback();
        throw error;
      });
    }
```

Comment: UPDATE: Just learned that as of 6/2/2018, Ember does not support async/await in code. Only in tests. ember-concurrency is the next best option.

Comment: thats not correct. you *can* use async/await. Just testing is a problem in some circumstances. What exactly is not working?

Comment: This is correct @Lux , you should avoid using async/await in app code for the time being, unless you are shipping out with the babel polyfill the native promise implementation is used and it is not run-loop aware, the conversation is best captured in the following [rfc](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/175).
Tl;dr use `ember-concurrency` or `ember-co` for now.

Comment: The autorun assertion what the comments above were about has been dropped: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/16797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, converted to async/await:

```
async save() {
    let tenant = this.modelFor(this.routeName).tenant;
    let app = this.modelFor(this.routeName).app;

    try {
        await tenant.save();

        try {
            await tenant.get('app').save({ adapterOptions: { tenantId: tenant.id }});
            this.transitionTo('tenants.tenant.info', tenant.id);
        } catch (error) {
            tenant.get('app').rollback();
            throw error;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        tenant.rollback();
        throw error;
    }
}
```

To convert from promises, you add the `await` keyword to method calls that return promises. Everything that you place in the `then` method of the promise you can simply put after the `await` statement.

The promises' `catch` methods convert to regular try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the answer Patrick Hund wrote, but attaching the catch statements to the promises being awaited, rather than wrapping in try/catch blocks, and extracting the error logic into a single function.

```
async save() {
    let tenant = this.modelFor(this.routeName).tenant;
    let app = this.modelFor(this.routeName).app;

    await tenant.save().catch(handleError.bind(this, false));
    await tenant.get('app').save({ adapterOptions: { tenantId: tenant.id }})
                .catch(handleError.bind(this, true));

    this.transitionTo('tenants.tenant.info', tenant.id);

    // isApp is bound via bind; error will be provided when called via catch        
    function handleError(isApp, error) {
        if (isApp) {
            tenant.get('app').rollback();
        } else {
            tenant.rollback();
        }
        throw error;
    }
}
```